# Set Membership Search Explanation

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have an SQL question asking me to perform a query without set membership search...Can somebody explain to me what this is? and the alternatives ...

Comment: Is there any context? Any extra information? Anything more you can add will likely make answers more useful and meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick & dirty:

Set membership behaves just like in math. You're looking for entities that exist in given a set.

SQL set membership can be done using IN operator. Set you are testing against can be static (`SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.attr IN(1, 2 ,3)` ) or result from subquery (just another query inside `IN` section). When using subquery, a projection of subquery must be done on attribute you're comparing the results to. There is also a negation of membership, operator `NOT IN`

Alternatives? Well, it depends on a situation. Some can be done via `JOIN`, but to fully answer your question, you should provide some more info.